# Looping a copy to new workbook function across multiple tabs based on tab names in cell values

Tags: vba, excel, tabs

I want to copy data from each tab in a spreadsheet and save it as new workbooks. The original workbook has many tabs (approx 50) and one of these tabs set up for the macro to run data from, as there may be new tabs added in the future. The macro data tab contains the file location for each new workbook, the name of the tab and also some information used by another macro to e-mail these newly created workbooks to relevant parties.

The issue is getting the macro to recognize the tab names for finding the range to copy, as the tab names are listed in a cell. I am unsure if it is possible to use this list, or whether I add a sheet at the end to loop through all the sheets from a specified start location until that one with an if.

```
Sub Datacopy()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set ws = Sheets("email")

    For Each Cell In ws.Columns("B").Cells

        Dim file1 As String

        file1 = Cell.Offset(0, 3).Text

            Sheets("cell.value").Range("A1:L500").Copy
            Workbooks.Add.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme)
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteComments)
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file1
            ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Next Cell

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    MsgBox ("Finished making files!")

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets("cell.value").Range("A1:L500").Copy` try removing the `""` from `"cell.value"`?

Comment: also do you really want to loop through *every cell* in column B - `For Each Cell In ws.Columns("B").Cells`? You will be literally looping through *every* row, even blank ones - which will most likely cause your code to error.

Comment: Comes back with a runtime "Subscript out of range" error with and without the quotation marks

Comment: Yea I would do `For Each Cell In ws.Columns("B").usedrange` as @ScottHoltzman suggests.

Comment: I would like it to finish at the first blank, as all the relevant tabs will have an entry in column B. Is there a condition I can add to the end of `For Each Cell In ws.Columns("B").Cells` (for example I have `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` in another macro I made which uses the autofilter)

Comment: try `cell.Value2` (with no quotes) ... and `For Each Cell in ws.Range(ws.Range("B1"),ws.Range("B1").End(xlDown))` - which assumes the sheet names start in B1 and are contiguous rows until the end. This will also allow you to add more sheet names in the future and not affect the code.

Comment: My fault. `.usedrange` is not a valid method for column XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you. Note the following:

- Code assumes that on sheet "email" it has a header row which is row 1 and the actual data starts on row 2.
- It checks to see if the B column cell is a valid worksheet name in the workbook

I have verified that this code works properly and as intended based on your original post:

```
Sub Datacopy()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim rSheetNames As Range
    Dim rSheet As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("email")

    Set rSheetNames = wsData.Range("B2", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    If rSheetNames.Row < 2 Then Exit Sub    'No data

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    For Each rSheet In rSheetNames
        If Not Evaluate("ISERROR('" & rSheet.Text & "'!A1)") Then
            Set wsTemp = Sheets.Add
            Sheets(rSheet.Text).Range("A1:L500").Copy
            wsTemp.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme
            wsTemp.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteComments
            wsTemp.Move
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs rSheet.Offset(, 3).Text
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        End If
    Next rSheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

    MsgBox "Finished making files!"

End Sub
```